# Is there a word for expressing a week was full of news?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to specify that during a week someone has received quite a lot of news. Some were bad news and some were good news. And "newsful" doesn't seem to be a word.

The best I've found was "an eventful week".

But the [Google definition for eventful](https://www.google.com/search?&q=define+eventful) is "*marked by interesting or exciting events*". However, a lot of the news received weren't exciting at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in:

> It was a **busy** week of news for x!

**busy**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/busy)

> characterized by or sustaining much activity: a busy morning; a busy
>   street.

Answer (score 1):

Would "**news-laden**" work in your case? I see "**laden**" can be used with other words as a suffix "**-laden**".

> **Their week became news-laden.**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/laden

Answer (score 0):

You're right that *newsful* isn't a word; however, [**newsworthy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newsworthy) is:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : interesting enough to the general public to warrant reporting
>
> // On the contrary, the week was full of *newsworthy* moments and seriously great clothes.
> — *Vogue*, "Watch: Vogue’s Anna Wintour on the Best Collections at Milan Fashion Week," 25 Sep. 2018